# Rename file for all commits in a Git repository

Tags: git

I want to rename a file for all the commits in Git repository. Here's what I have tried:

```
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git mv -k <old name> <new name>' HEAD
```

This command went through all the commits in the repository, but it ended up with the message:

> WARNING: Ref 'refs/heads/master' is unchanged

which means nothing had been changed. What had been wrong here?

Note that the file which I wanted to rename doesn't exist from the first commit. Therefore if I do not use `-k` in `git mv`, I mean if I use:

```
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git mv <old name> <new name>' HEAD`
```

Git would error out while trying the first commit saying something like "bad source...".

Comment: you're going to change history with that.

Comment: Yes, that is the point of filter-branch.

Comment: I understand that "filter-branch" is all about rewriting history which is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Can you try with `--tree-filter`? I know it will be slower than index-only, but if it works …

Comment: Yes, I did try "tree-filter", like this:

$ git filter-branch --tree-filter 'mv `<old name> <new name>`' HEAD

The problem was that the file I wanted to rename does not exist from first
commit, therefor git errors out with "mv: cannot stat `<old name>`': No such file or director"

How can I test whether the file exsit or not before "mv" command?

Comment: Duplicate of [filter-branch --index-filter always failing with "fatal: bad source"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15028580/filter-branch-index-filter-always-failing-with-fatal-bad-source)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I finally solved my original problem by using:

```bash
git filter-branch --tree-filter '
if [ -f <old name> ]; then
  mv <old name> <new name>
fi' --force HEAD
```

Comment: For a solution using `--index-filter`, please refer to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15029691/572644)

Comment: Note that `git mv` doesn't work with an index-filter, because `git mv` needs a working copy, which you only get with a tree-filter.

Comment: Replace `if [ -f <old name> ]` with `if [ -d <old name> ]` to rename a directory instead of a file.

Answer (score 7):

Nowadays it is best to use **filter-repo** - https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo :

```
git filter-repo --path-rename full/path/to/file.old:full/path/to/file.new
```

See my own blog page: http://ben.goodacre.name/tech/Rename-file-for-all-previous-commits-in-Git

Comment: git-filter-repo is great if your git version is new enough.

Comment: Why would you be using an old git version? 2.22 is 2 years old now.

Comment: I always use the newest git (with archlinux), but there are still people who don't have a choice, and are stuck on older versions of git.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone interested in just renaming a file - `git rebase -i` will work just fine. Include the commit that created the file in the rebase, mark it with `edit`, and just rename the file. Git will apply the next commits to this file correctly.

Comment: that works, but requires you to manually rename the file for every commit.  No big deal if it's one commit, but a filter-branch will cleanup the whole branch in one pass

Comment: when I tried it @STW I just had to rename the file in the one commit that created it, it really surprised me (in a good way) that git was smart enough to apply modifications in the renamed file afterwards

Comment: yep, and if you just need to go back a commit or two it's a faster and safer approach.  Choose your weapon wisely!  And yeah, git is epic

Comment: this creates a new commit from your HEAD commit with the file renamed but if you look in the history you will see that the file still has the old name, i.e. it will not help if you `rebase` onto another branch with the same file

Comment: even when you include the new commit with the renamed file @MihaiSoloi

Answer (score 0):

I used "git-filter-repo --force --filename-callback" for bulk rename files in the CMS/CMF EffCore project repository.

Here is an example of a working version of the script for renaming **file names**.

```
git-filter-repo --force --filename-callback '
# rename '*._style' to '*.css'
  if filename.endswith(b"._style"):
    return filename[:-7] + b".css"
# rename '*._script' to '*.js'
  elif filename.endswith(b"._script"):
    return filename[:-8] + b".js"
# default case
  else:
    return filename
  '
```

Here is an example of a working version of the script for **renaming file paths**.

```
git-filter-repo \
  --path-rename modules/core/:system/module_core/ \
  --path-rename modules/data/:system/module_data/ \
  --path-rename modules/demo/:system/module_develop/module_demo/
```