# filter-branch --index-filter always failing with "fatal: bad source"

Tags: git

So, I am trying to rename a folder in my repository using `git filter-branch --index-filter`, but I always end up with a "fatal: bad source" error.

The problem is easily demonstrated on a test repository using a file instead of a folder.

Preparation:

```
$ git init
$ echo whatever >> my_file.txt
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "initial"
$ echo whatever2 >> my_file2.txt
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "second"
```

Now, I am trying to change `my_file.txt` to `your_file.txt`:

```
$ git filter-branch --index-filter 'git mv my_file.txt your_file.txt' HEAD
```

But it doesn't work:

```
Rewrite dac9a2023bdf9dd0159fab46213d9e1342ae9f75 (1/2)fatal: bad source, source=my_file.txt, destination=your_file.txt
index filter failed: git mv my_file.txt your_file.txt
```

However, the very same `git mv` command executed normally works without problems:

```
$ git mv my_file.txt your_file.txt
$ git status
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#       renamed:    my_file.txt -> your_file.txt
#
```

I am sure, I am missing something essential here - but what is it?

Comment: My guess is that in that particular commit, `my_file.txt` doesn't exist, which causes `git mv` to fail - you might try `git mv -k -f` instead. Also, `git mv` is not really appropriate for an `--index-filter` since it affects more than just the index - that should probably be a `--tree-filter` instead.

Comment: @twalberg: Your guess is not correct. `git rm [...] my_file.txt` works without problems in the --index-filter...

Comment: @twalberg: But I guess the second part of your comment is the "answer": It simply doesn't work.

Comment: `--index-filter` does not check out the tree for each commit, which gives it better efficiency, but, since it basically leaves the working directory alone, I don't think `git mv` is going to consistently do what you expect. It may "work", but it may give you unexpected results...

Comment: @twalberg: Thanks for your comments. It makes sense, I didn't really think about what `git mv` does. All samples of `git rm` always use the `--cached` option to only work on the index. I found an answer based on the man page, though.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As twalberg points out in his answer, git mv doesn't just access the index, it also access the disk. That's probably the reason why it doesn't work.

I didn't want to use the slow `--tree-filter` so I tried to change the sample from the `git filter-branch` man page that shows how to move the complete repository into a subfolder.

The result is this - and it actually works ;-)

```bash
git filter-branch --index-filter '
git ls-files -s | \
sed "s-\(\t\"*\)my_file.txt-\1your_file.txt-" | \
GIT_INDEX_FILE=$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new git update-index --index-info && \
mv "$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new" "$GIT_INDEX_FILE"
' HEAD
```

Comment: For a more detailed explanation of the above script, see this blog post: [Renaming The Past With Git](http://www.fussylogic.co.uk/blog/?p=1250).

Comment: I used your answer to [help someone who was also working on a renaming problem](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23842072/456814), along with a detailed explanation. Thanks for the tip `;)`

Answer (score 4):

`git mv` is not really appropriate in an `--index-filter` clause. Since `--index-filter` does not check out each commit it's rewriting into the working directory, and `git mv` operates on the working directory (in addition to the index), using `git mv` in `--index-filter` will not accomplish what is expected. Use a `--tree-filter` instead. (It might be possible to accomplish this still with `--index-filter` by using `git update-index` instead, but I don't have that available off the top of my head).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. `update-index` is what I am using. Honestly, I don't really know how it is working, I just took the sample from the man-page and tweaked the regular expression passed to `sed` :)

Comment: `--tree-filter` is not really an option for me, because my real world scenario is to fix different casings of the same directory.

Comment: Ouch. In that case, maybe you ought to consider doing the work on a Windows box (ugh, can't believe I just said that...) where the different casings will not cause as much pain in the event you do need to check them out for some reason (`--tree-filter` or otherwise)...

Comment: I am working on a windows box all along. :) That's the reason why `--tree-filter` is a bad idea. I would have to do `mv CASE case_tmp && mv case_tmp case` with `CASE` being the wrong case and `case` the correct.

Comment: I am actually quite happy with the `update-index` solution I found. It's fast and painless.