# How to batch-replace *all* instances (content, filenames and commit messages) of *Foo* to *Bar* in a repo in a single, simple step?

Tags: git, replace, repository, git-rewrite-history, bfg-repo-cleaner

Suppose I have a giant repo for an as-of-yet unpublished software product called ["Hammerstein"](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minister_von_Hammerstein), written by the famous German software company "Apfel" of which I am an employee.

One day, "Apfel" spins out the Hammerstein division and sells it to the even *more* famous company "Oráculo" which renames "Hammerstein" to ["Reineta"](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manzana_reineta) as a matter of national pride and decides to open source it.

Agreements mandate that **all** references to "Hammerstein" and "Apfel" be replaced by "Oráculo" and "Reineta" in the repository.

All filenames, all commit messages, *everything* must be replaced.

So, for example:

1. `src/core/ApfelCore/main.cpp` must become `src/core/OraculoCore/main.cpp`.
2. The commit message that says `"Add support for Apfel Groupware Server"` must become `"Add support for Oraculo Groupware Server"`
3. The strings `ApfelServerInstance* local_apfel`, `#define REINETA` and `Url("http://apfel.de")` must become `OraculoServerInstance* local_oraculo`, `#define HAMMERSTEIN`, etc.

This applies to **files that are not in `HEAD` anymore as well.**

What is the **simplest** and most pain-free method to achieve it with **minimal manual intervention** (so that it can be applied in batch to a potentially large number of repositories/assets)?

1. [BFG](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) can replace the strings, but it seems to only have a `--delete-file` option, not a `--rename-file`, and even then it does not take patterns as an argument
2. [This approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9984722/git-rename-many-files-and-folders) seems to work only for `HEAD` and not for the whole history; I have had no luck using it with `--tree-filter`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Full disclosure: I'm the author of the [BFG Repo-Cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/)*

As you say in the question, the BFG supports replacing file content with the `--replace-text` flag - but this flag does not extend to file *names* and commit messages. So, what alterations to the codebase would it take to make the BFG's `--replace-text` operation extend to those too?

This comes down to hooking in some new [`Cleaner[V]`](https://github.com/rtyley/bfg-repo-cleaner/blob/v1.12.5/bfg-library/src/main/scala/com/madgag/git/bfg/cleaner/package.scala#L23-L25) implementations, where `V` is the type of thing you want to clean (a commit message, a directory listing), and the `Cleaner` just has the job of producing a new, clean `V` from an old, dirty `V`. To perform the actual text change, you can re-use the same [text-replacing function](https://github.com/rtyley/bfg-repo-cleaner/blob/v1.12.5/bfg/src/main/scala/com/madgag/git/bfg/cli/CLIConfig.scala#L164) used for file content changes.

#### File Names

Use a `Cleaner[Seq[Tree.Entry]]` - 'tree' is what Git calls folders ('file tree') - so you would just update the `FileName` on each `Tree.Entry`.

#### Commit Messages

Use a `Cleaner[CommitNode]` - again, you're just replacing text on the `message` field - see the [CommitMessageObjectIdsUpdater](https://github.com/rtyley/bfg-repo-cleaner/blob/v1.12.5/bfg-library/src/main/scala/com/madgag/git/bfg/cleaner/ObjectIdSubstitutor.scala#L28-L32) for a very close example for what you're trying to do. While you're there, you could do something with the author and committer email addresses if you wanted to (eg purge `...@apfel.com`, I guess).

### Speed

As mentioned by @VonC in his answer, `filter-branch` *can* do both these replacements (file name & commit message) but while the `--msg-filter` flag should do the commit message updates reasonably quickly, I believe `filter-branch` will be fairly **excruciatingly** slow for renaming files within a large code base like yours. The BFG, optimised for exactly this kind of operation, will be several *hundred* times faster.

The BFG accepts donations at **https://www.bountysource.com/teams/bfg-repo-cleaner** - so if you'd like to support development of this feature,  or if you just found the BFG useful in solving your problem, that's where you can make a difference.

Comment: There no words to describe how incredibly awesome this answer is. There *are*, in fact, words to describe *why* it is so awesome, but those who can appreciate its awesomeness in full don't need them anyway. I wish I could upvote twice.

Comment: I won't probably need this feature anytime soon since @VonC's method with some additional scripting and `awk`ward `awk`ing did it for me - *but*, if I tried to implement it for the sheer, um, fun, would you consider evaluating a PR for it?

Comment: 'some additional scripting and awkward awking did it for me' - ah, so the filename renaming was not very slow? I thought I saw in your question a mention that this was a very large codebase, but re-reading your question I see you don't specifically mention that. Out of curiosity, how big are these repos? (number of commits, file count in a snapshot of your filetree) - and how long does the filter-branch index-filter run take?

Comment: Nice! The idea of BFG doing commit message and file names replacement is exiting.

Comment: 'if I tried to implement it for the sheer, um, fun, would you consider evaluating a PR for it?' - do it for the fun! Exposing this stuff in a nice way in the command line arguments (that makes sense for the entire audience of the BFG) would take a bit more discussion, but if you're willing to play around with Scala, I think you'll find hacking in a rough-and-ready solution quite entertaining.

Comment: @RobertoTyley: *tolerably* slow. We are talking a few thousand commits per repo and maybe ~50KLOC total. My problem was more along the lines of "I have a bunch of biggish repos that other teams have worked on, and I want to replace all instances of the forbidden words in an automagic fashion, without having to know or care too much about the repo contents, all while staying, em, safe from possible repercussions :-)"

Answer (score 2):

> in a single, simple step?

Not single, and not so simple, but possible:

---

For updating commit message, you would need to use `the --msg-filter` of [`git filter-branch`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch)

```
git filter-branch -f --msg-filter 'sed "s/Apfel/Oraculo/"' -- --all
```

Note the `--all`, in order to [filter in all commits of every branches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7430801/6309).
You might have to repeat that command several times for taking care of different case.

---

For moving files (without using --tree-filter), you can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15029691/6309) (and [this article](http://www.fussylogic.co.uk/blog/?p=1250)), and adapt it in order to build the new path:

```
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git ls-files -s | \
  sed "s,/ApfelCore/,/OraculoCore/," | \
  GIT_INDEX_FILE=$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new git update-index --index-info && \
  mv "$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new" "$GIT_INDEX_FILE"' \
-- --all
```

---

As mentioned, [BFG](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) can replace all strings; see "[How to substitute text from files in git history?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15730571/6309)"

```
java -jar bfg.jar --replace-text replacements.txt my-repo.git
```

> The `replacements.txt` file should contain all the substitutions you want to do, in a format like this (one entry per line)

```
Apfel==>Oraculo
apfel==>oraculo
REINETA==>HAMMERSTEIN
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is a very nice starting point that got me out of the pits of despair (I was attempting to use `find ... | xargs replace ...` with `--tree-filter` without much luck), but one would probably want something like `sed -e "s,Apfel,Oraculo," -e "s,Hammerstein,Reineta," -e "s,apfel,oraculo,"` in order to rename *all* relevant files.