# git change file in all commits and tags

Tags: git

I have a file that I need to change for the entire history of the repo to be something different.

This means all tags too

I don't think this is possible; do you know of a way?

The reason is I have a build script that I need to change for all previous tags and commits.

So when I checkout the tag; the build script will not be valid anymore and I need to change this file in the past for all tags too.

The workaround I have now is to symlink the folder in place that the build script depends on; which is acceptable; but would still like to know if rewriting history is possible too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rename file for all commits in git repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9446689/rename-file-for-all-commits-in-git-repository)

Answer (score 0):

It is certainly possible, but be aware that going back and changing past history will make life difficult for anybody else who also has a copy of the repository.

A good explanation of how to do this is at GitHub's [Remove sensitive data](https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data/) help page. This uses the powerful `git filter-branch` command to rewrite the entire history for a branch. The example is for removing a file with a password, but a similar technique can be used to modify the contents of a file.

You may with to carefully consider whether you *really* need to do this. It will be highly disruptive to others.

Comment: I am the only person using this repo. I am looking for a set of commands that will update all tags, commits to have the new file throughout history. It is not super necessary but would be a big help. The problem is the folder that is being referenced in the build script has a new time. For now I can symlink; but it would be nice to NOT need to do that.

Comment: Okay, well if you're the only one using it then you don't have to worry about disrupting others. The `git filter-branch` command can change the history for a single branch. If you have more than one branch, you'll have to do that for *each* branch. And then you'll have to re-tag your tags, because they don't change even if you rewrite the branch they pointed to. Overall, this is probably going to be a heck of a lot of work for you, and you'll have to decide whether that work is worth the effort.

Comment: `git filter-branch` can filter multiple branches, and using `--tag-filter cat` will make it adjust tags too.  It's still a big pain (and it's hard to get right), but it can do the job in [one swell foop](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/71769/what-is-the-origin-of-in-one-fell-swoop#comment138860_71771).