# git - How to Don't checkout a file or folder

Tags: windows, git

We have a repo. A coworker check in a folder in linux. I want to check it out in Windows. There are some filenames(e.g. ABC::DEF.3pm.gz) what Windows doesn't.
It fail when I run

git pull origin

Is there a way to ignore this folder?

I've tried put this folder in .gitignore and it doesn't work as this folder's already in repo.

Comment: Its better to delete this folder from the repo than finding a way to not checkout part of the files (which I'm not sure this option exists)

Comment: delete .git folder in windows and clone the proyect from repo again.

Comment: Will I lost my change if delete .git and clone again?

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible solutions.

**Sparse checkout**

Sparse checkout is a Git feature which allows to checkout only specific files and directories. See examples and further discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13738951/7018603).

**Filter-branch**

Another solution would be renaming that file across whole repository with `git filter-branch` as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9458637/7018603) answer. That would help to get rid of issue at all, however it would also rewrite commit history.