# GIT - Renaming file|directory from the first time the file is created

Tags: git

**Situation:**

I have a git commit shown as below:
`C1` - `C2` - `CN+1` - `C50`

In `C1`, I created a file name `foo.txt`
And, in `C2`, `C3`, `CN+1` I start committing the change to `foo.txt` file.

When im in `C50` commit, I want to rename the `foo.txt` filename into `bar.txt`

**By doing:** `git mv foo.txt bar.txt`
I will have the commit result as:
`C1` - `C2` - `CN+1` - `C50` - `C51`

Where, `C51` commit message example: `rename foo.txt to bar.txt`

**I also tried:**

1. Checkout to `C1` commit
2. Perform `git mv` with `append` option that will create a `C1'` commit
3. Checkout to `C50` commit
4. Rebase `C50` commit to `C1'` commit. And I have to repair some conflict, but no problem
   Result: Perform this will end up with what I want. The file being rename from the beginning. But I have to perform the same way as for `C2`, `CN+1`, `C50`. Thats a lot of work to do

**Expected:**
How do I achieve commit that have structure as:
`C1` - `C2` - `CN+1` - `C50`

Where, the file `foo.txt` in `C1` commit is like never been created but use `bar.txt` instead. And all commit after `C1`. That is, `C2` commit until `C50` commit know. It's not a new file from beginning. Instead it has been rename from beginning and writing it's content to `bar.txt`

Also, if I just rename the directory, I expect same kind of output

**Reason**:
I don't want to keep any git log|status regarding of it

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you want, so let me try to rephrase it: you want to rewrite history in order to pretend `foo.txt` never existed and just have it be `bar.txt` from the very beginning, right? You *possibly* know this, but you can't do that without rewriting the commit ids (i.e. make the branch/repo incompatible with others who have already checked it out with `foo.txt` in it).

Comment: Look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69351965/717372